# Display of axes in a saved matplotlib.pyplot figure in Visual Studio Code seems to depend on the conda environment used(?)

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

A while ago I created a figure in `matplotlib.pyplot` using this kind of code:

```
cl = pd.read_csv(path)
ax = sns.relplot(data = cl, x = "trial parameter", y = "value", markers = True, kind = "line")
(ax.set_axis_labels(xaxis_title_for_clustering_plot, yaxis_title_for_clustering_plot)
   .set_titles(title_for_clustering_plot))
plt.savefig(path_clustering_plot, bbox_inches='tight')
```

The .png was saved and it displayed the axes correctly, both if I opened it in Windows Photos or if I clicked on it in Visual Studio Code (VSC). This is what VSC showed (I am not showing the axes titles here for confidentiality reasons, but they are there):

[image]

Now I ran again the *exact same* code with the *exact same* data; the only part that changed was the conda environment that I used. And (at least) two things changed: 1) the figure was smaller (worse resolution); 2) by clicking on the .png in Visual Studio Code, the axes and ticks were covered with a sort of checkered pattern:

[image]

This is really annoying; I have not changed anything in the code, and it behaves differently.

**Would you have any suggestion on what could be causing this and what I could do to make the new environment behave in the same way as the old one?**
Some version issues? Some global parameter that is set in a different way in the two environments?

[Goes without saying, I need to use the new environment, I have no option to do this work in the old one; and still, I think it's important to understand why such things happen].

---

**EDIT 1:** following up from Jody Klymak's comment

Versions of `matplotlib` in the two environments (left = new, right = old):

[image]

Note however that I am using `seaborn` (sorry, I did not mention that `sns` was from `import seaborn as sns`).
So I am still stuck, because `ax` is not the same as in `plt`, where `fig, ax` are generated:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/color_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-color-color-demo-py

And the code I see here:

https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html

does not seem to help, either.

Any suggestions are welcome.
This is really hard work for plotting a simple graph... :(

Comment: The figure facecolor is white in one of your plots and transparent in another.  Matplotlib changed the defaults but it was a long time ago so your old environment must be quite old.